# Redux state management with class

Tags: javascript, timer, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a Timer class, which allows me to Pause/Restart a `setInterval` in JS:

```js
export class Timer {
  constructor(callback, delay) {
    this.callback = callback
    this.delay = delay
    this.remaining = delay
    this.start = undefined
    this.timerId = undefined
  }
  pause() {
    window.clearTimeout(this.timerId)
    this.pauseTime = new Date().getTime()
    this.remaining -= new Date() - this.start
  }
  resume() {
    this.start = new Date().getTime()
    window.clearTimeout(this.timerId)
    this.timerId = window.setTimeout(this.callback, this.remaining)
  }
  quit() {
    window.clearTimeout(this.timerId)
  }
}
```

My (Bound) Redux Action Creators are as follows:

```js
export const boundPomodoroStartFinish = () => {
  let id = new Date().getTime()
  let pomodoroTime = 1000
  let timer = new Timer(() => {
    let pomodoro = store.getState().pomodoro
    let time = new Date().getTime()
    store.dispatch(pomodoroFinish(pomodoro, time))
  }, pomodoroTime)
  timer.resume()
  store.dispatch(pomodoroStart(id, timer))
}

export const boundPomodoroPause = () => {
  let pomodoro = store.getState().pomodoro
  let time = new Date().getTime()
  pomodoro.timer.pause()
  store.dispatch(pomodoroPause(time))
}

export const boundPomodoroQuit = () => {
  let pomodoro = store.getState().pomodoro
  let time = new Date().getTime()
  pomodoro.timer.quit()
  store.dispatch(pomodoroQuit(pomodoro, time))
}

export const boundPomodoroResume = () => {
  let pomodoro = store.getState().pomodoro
  pomodoro.timer.resume()
  store.dispatch(pomodoroResume())
}
```

It feels like I shouldn't be calling `pomodoro.timer.x()` in the bound Action Creators, but should instead be sending the pomodoro to the reducers and having the reducers call the action.

Alternatively, I can get rid of the class entirely and put the entire `setInterval` time management into the `store` and have the reducers always calculate it there and only there (after the appropriate action is called)- but that just seems more complicated than necessary.

What is the right Redux way of doing things? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New to this as well, but I think you should look at creating a Redux middleware for this.

http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

One of the examples uses clearTimeout.

Comment: I'm not sure that Middleware is the way to go for this. I'm not just wanting to delay particular actions, but I'm recording that (time) data within my state itself.

Comment: Been doing some more reading, take a look as Redux-Saga and rx-react for two possible solutions.